# jquery json return data adding two numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, addition

I'm using Jquery post method to get data from php file which returned a a multidimensional array which has productid, name and price in it in the following format

```
[
    { product_id: 34, product_name: "Coca-Cola", price: 0.7 },
    { product_id: 24, product_name: "Shredded Beef Steak Wrap", price: 2.99 }
]
```

when i add them those two prices it does not add up together infect they concatenate. 
this is how i'm trying to add them up

```
$.each(data, function(i, result) {
    //total  = total + +result.price;
    //total += +result.price;
    //total += result.price;
    //total += +total + +result.price;
    //total = total * 1 + result.price;
});
$("#cart_total").empty();
$("#cart_total").append(output);
```

Any idea what should i do to get this right

Regards

Comment: What you want total of price ?

Comment: Before your `$.each` loop you have to initialize `total=0` it work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```js
var data = [
    { product_id: 34, product_name: "Coca-Cola", price: 0.7 },
    { product_id: 24, product_name: "Shredded Beef Steak Wrap", price: 2.99 }
];

var sum = 0;
data.forEach(function(i){ 
   sum =sum + +i.price;  
});
alert(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
total = Number(total) + Number(total.price);
```

Concatenation happens because `total` must be a string, even if it "contains" a number. In other words:

```
'1' === 1
```

Means `false` in javascript.

What we're doing is coercing `total` string to a number:

```
Number('1') === 1
```

(`true`)

Comment: `!=== ` sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [
    { product_id: 34, product_name: "Coca-Cola", price: 0.7 },
    { product_id: 24, product_name: "Shredded Beef Steak Wrap", price: 2.99 }
];
```

To add

```
var sum = 0;
data.forEach(function(i){ 
   sum += +i.price;  
});
$("#cart_total").empty();
$("#cart_total").append(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

> You have to initialize `total` variable before loop started and you can perform your task.

```
total = 0;
$.each(data, function(i, result) {
    total  = total + result.price;
});
alert(total);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/onvnxqLj/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [
    { product_id: 34, product_name: "Coca-Cola", price: 0.7 },
    { product_id: 24, product_name: "Shredded Beef Steak Wrap", price: 2.99 }
];
```

Then calcultate sum :

```
var total =  0;
$(data).each(function(index,item) {
    total += item.price;
});
total = parseFloat(total.toFixed(2))
```

Display :

```
$("#result").html(total);
```

Working exemple here : http://jsfiddle.net/9jpdLkp2/

Comment: btw how do you only show two digits after decimal? if you could help

Comment: total = parseFloat(total.toFixed(2)) , added in my answer

Answer (score 1):

User parseInt function :

```
sum=parseInt(price)+parseInt(price);
```

Answer (score 1):

initialize total firstly : total = 0;
then :

```
total += parseFloat(result.price);
```

try this!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var total =  0;
$(data).each(function(index,item) {
    total += item.price;
});
total = parseFloat(total.toFixed(2));
```

`toFixed(2)` is to restrict two digits after decimal

hope that helps